# Dynamic LINQ cast to nullable

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate, dynamic-linq

I'm using Dynamic LINQ with NHibernate.
Simple example demonstrates my problem:

```
var q = sess.Query<User>().Select("new (Id, Login, Person.Id as PersonId)");
```

throws NullReferenceException when where are Users in database with User.Person == null.

This solves the problem:

```
var q = sess.Query<User>().Select(new { Id, Login, PersonId = (long?)Person.Id });
```

**but I need something like**

```
var q = sess.Query<User>().Select("new (Id, Login, (long?)Person.Id as PersonId)");
```

because select expression is generated dynamically.
Unfortunately dynamic LINQ does not understand cast to (long?) :(

What should I have to do?
Thanks in advance!

**==== Edit ====**

Ok, I understood two things:
1. Dynamic LINQ does not know about long, only Int64.
2. Cast is not '(Int64)something' but 'Int64(something)'.
So whole my code should be

```
sess.Query<User>().Select("new (Id, Login, Int64?(Person.Id) as PersonId)");
```

But it still does not solve my whole problem because NHibernate now fails with Could not execute query[SQL: SQL not available] exception and NullReference inner exception.

Comment: why you try `Person.Id` in dynamic linq code, but in simple linq you use `(long?)PersonId`?

Comment: do you try `var q = sess.Query<User>().Select("new (Id, Login, PersonId )");`?

Comment: Sorry, it was a typing error, correct is var q = sess.Query<User>().Select(new { Id, Login, PersonId = (long?)Person.Id });

Comment: can you provide sample of `User` and `Person` classes? also can  `Person` be null?

Comment: Example: class User { public long Id {get;set;} public string Login {get;set;} public Person Person {get;set;} }

Comment: class Person { public long Id {get;set;} } Yes, User.Person can be null.

Comment: you can try use workaround with `IIF` function

Comment: I tried var q = sess.Query<User>().Select("new (Id, Login, (Person==null?0:Person.Id) as PersonId)"), it works, but generates non-optimal SQL query - requests all fields of User and Person tables, not only User.Id, User.Person.Id and User.Login (in this example).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I have mastered the problem. I studied Dynamic.cs and found that the Dynamic LINQ's syntax is very specific. Particularly the string expression "SomeType(SomeExpression)" generates cast expression only if SomeType has no constructor with one parameter. In other case it generates "new SomeType(SomeExpression)". I considered it as a mistake and slightly modified the Dynamic.cs.

Now in my example the cast can be made as 'Int64? Person.Id'. It is not a "normal" cast syntax but it works for me like a charm. Dynamic ExpressionParser is pretty good but unfortunately is not well adapted for C# cast syntax.

Also I registered in Dynamic.cs short type names like "long", "int" etc.

The modified source is downloadable here: http://1drv.ms/1cRJtSP .

Comment: Thank you!!! I diffed the source code you provided and edited your answer with the actual changes needed. I using a modified version of Dynamic Linq so I needed to make the changes manually.